# Can a punishment be implemented for using the word "vertice" in a Q/A?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

**<sarcasm>**

Of course, the problem is also pervasive within the Youtube tutorial world.  But it would be nice, even in this this small bastion of BSE hope, if we could change the modeling world for the better.

Just a few possibilities:

- Automatically deduct 5 points until the mangling of language is removed.
- Lose asking/answering privileges for a week as a way to contemplate the grievous nature of your error.
- Be required to type "Vertex, not Vertice" into a text box 100 times before being allowed back on the site.

I realize this may seem a bit harsh but I think the potential rewards are well worth it. I understand that English is not everyone's primary language, but then again, [neither is Latin](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=vertex).  That's simply not an excuse.

Is this a feature that can be implemented?  If so, what would be the method of chastening? **</sarcasm>**

[Just trying to add some humor to your day :D ]

Comment: Just a thought - :)

Comment: So there should be <sarcasm> tags somewhere around here?

Comment: @MrZak - I couldn't get it to work

Comment: Oh my... If this gets built then I think the next feature should be something to do with sarcasm on the meta.

Comment: @MrZak - mine too

Comment: Yep, I guess tag for comments should be added as well. Sarcasm again.

Comment: @David - I totally agree

Comment: \*looks for offended people\* \*only sees sarcasm and apologies\* I think it's fine :)

Comment: We must use the one true spelling: Vertexyishthingymajiggies.

Answer (score 7):

Oh my. And I thought "Vertexes" was bad.. Anyway, this isn't going to be implemented (it's up to SE to add features, and I doubt this is one they'd be interested in).

Instead, please feel free to [edit posts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/editing) to address things like this.

Comment: Hehe, I know.  I can't for the life of me understand why this wouldn't implemented :)

Comment: Just for the record: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vertex

Comment: @cegaton I know, but I still don't like it..

Answer (score 4):

Bit harsh don't you think? There are probably more pressing concerns than typos in questions and points should reflect post quality not grammar correctness I think.

It is a common mistake even among native English speakers which are probably not even a majority here, and with no overall discernible gains to site quality or usability, other than language correctness. I mean everyone understands "vertice" and "vertices" even though they mean vertex.

[Community](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) user might possibly be programmed to automatically fix that, it already fixes some common mistakes and typos here and there, but I don't know if it is user configurable, nor if can be assigned custom tasks like this.

However making it do proofing on all stack exchange posts might not be a sensible use of server load resources, and that is the task of spellcheckers after all.

Anyway my suggestion is that you edit them yourself, the original author generally gets notified and shown a diff, thus achieving your objecting of improving overall grammar.

You can also leave a comment with your edit pointing to the mistake, and downvote the post if deserved.

Comment: But seriously, I was 99.8% kidding

Comment: Sure eheh It has been suggested before, there should be an official sarcasm font