# Candidate score

Tags: discussion, election

When an election rolls around the nominees are assigned a [candidate score](https://data.stackexchange.com/blender/query/298418/candidate-score). A  maximum possible score of 40, constructed fifty fifty from reputation and selected badge achievements.

**Reputation**

1 point for each 1000 of rep, capped at 20,

**Badges**

A point per having any of

**Moderation Badges.**

'Civic Duty',
'Cleanup',
'Deputy',
'Electorate',
'Marshal',
'Sportsmanship',
'Reviewer',
'Steward'

**Participation**

'Constituent',
'Convention',
'Enthusiast',
'Investor',
'Quorum',
'Yearling'

**Editing**

'Organizer',
'Copy Editor',
'Explainer',
'Refiner',
'Tag Editor',
'Strunk & White'

Some example scores. *Note: I've chosen by league table, & activity. If you are on here and don't want to be edit yourself out, or conversely not on here, and want to be edit yourself in.  Please include your score in any answers*

UserIds 15543, 19307, 74827, 31447, 19156, 34531, 3710, 35559, 41069, 60759, 15924, 78972, 86891, 241, 30849, 29586, 599, 92768, 2217, 7777

```
User Link                Total CappedRep BadgeCount ModBadges EditingBadges ParticipationBadges 

------------------------ ----- --------- ---------- --------- ------------- ------------------- 

David                    40    20        20         8         6             6                       
Ray Mairlot              38    20        18         7         6             5                       
Duarte Farrajota Ramos   38    20        18         8         6             4                       
batFINGER                38    20        18         7         6             5                       
gandalf3                 38    20        18         6         6             6                       
Leander                  34    20        14         5         4             5                       
Robin Betts              32    20        12         4         3             5                       
lemon                    31    20        11         3         3             5                       
Jaroslav Jerryno Novotny 31    20        11         3         3             5                       
p2or                     28    12        16         7         5             4                       
Rich Sedman              28    20        8          2         2             4                       
Jachym Michal            27    17        10         3         3             4                       
Robert Gützkow           27    18        9          3         3             3                       
moonboots                25    20        5          1         2             2                       
Martynas Žiemys          23    12        11         4         3             4                       
Timaroberts              19    7         12         5         4             3                       
brockmann                17    6         11         5         3             3                       
susu                     15    6         9          3         3             3                       
Gorgious                 13    8         5          2         2             1                       
Grimm                    13    1         12         5         3             4
```

**Too Reputation-centric**

IMO this is way too reputation centric. In sport the best *player* doesn't necessarily make the best captain, and often affects their *playing* if capped. The addict that hovers over the questions, often duplicates, answering first to get their "fix" is not going to fit the bill either.

*How about base 10  `log(rep) - 2` capped at 0 to 6, (A hundred is 0, a thousand 1 and a million 6)?.*

**Badges**

*Drop rep and simply Order the table above by badges either total or in a badge category order , or weighted more to some than others..*?

A review queue badge is obtained by doing so many reviews. All of which may have been rejected, or gone the other way. In the heady days of trying to beat @David at the review sweep, many times I didn't pass when undecided. Made the decision to cease review for a category once I hit 1000, get the medal, tour of duty over.  Others have gone way and beyond.  This should count for something.

What skill badges to the incumbents have? Do we add some weight to mixing up the skill set of the moderation team. Something using our score for the  most popular tags?

**Voting**.

One of my soapbox issues on BSE is the lack of voting. Do blender users have particularly [high standards](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6856/high-standards-top-100-users-that-rarely-upvote)?  Could a penalty be incurred for [not voting at all](https://data.stackexchange.com/blender/query/1098871/highest-rep-without-ever-voting)?, for each time [vertice or vertexes](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2387/can-a-punishment-be-implemented-for-using-the-word-vertice-in-a-q-a?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C22.1594) is used in a post or comment?. ... starting a question with "So, I need..."  Posting "It doesn't work in 2.9" comments on posts pre 2014.... oops got onto penalties and digressed..

Voting is important. And is well covered via  "Civic Duty", "Electorate", "Enthusiast", "Sportsmanship" badges.  Still way outweighed by rep.

[Interesting queries on Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49943/interesting-queries-on-data-explorer)

**The question**

What criteria would you use to determine a candidate score.

Be both OTT and sensible, ruthless and fair. Most importantly please add those one percenters (up or down), that count to you.

For "consistency sake"  cap `score + bonuses - penalties` to 0, 40.
.

Comment: You got me with *vertexes* :). I'd agree that reputation points aren't a reliable measure of moderating qualities (look at mine :). Rep doesn't matter to me, as long as the mod knows what he's doing.

Comment: [Vertexes](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vertexes) isn't necessarily wrong, depending on how strict you are. I'd rather have penalties for using "Plz Help" or writing the words "Question" or "Doubt" in the title. XD

Comment: Anyway nice post, I gather this all came from Stack Data site. Your scoring system seems more reasonable.@batfinger your score is right up there at the top. What are you doing here playing with numbers, instead of running as candidate? :D

Comment: David added the query as a link to election page for me at your election.  I cannot resist any chance to post that vertices meta link. Someone took it just a  weeeeeee bit too seriously.   And like the election prior  there are already some very good candidates who have put their hand up. There is one potential candidate who is also a high rep  member of "Seasoned Advice" SE that would make a great mod whom has expressed interest in the future... My advice:  _"The future is now!"_

Comment: I knew I couldn't be the only one who noticed @batFINGER :). Having high rep on "Seasoned Advice" tells you so much about a person... *"The future is now!"*

Comment: What about helpful flags as a metric too?

Comment: @marcellothearcane sure. The question then is how much  for how many.. eg 1 pt bonus for >= one per month of users lifespan?